# 「rpm -qa | grep -i imagemagick」で結果が表示されるのに、convertコマンドが使えない理由は？

Tags: centos, imagemagick

**Q1.imagemagickはインストール済ですか？**
ライブラリだけがインストールされていて、本体は入っていない状態ですか？

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i imagemagick
ImageMagick6-libs-6.9.9.39-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

**Q2.今どういう状況ですか？**
convertのパスを確認する方法は？

```
# convert -version
bash: convert: コマンドが見つかりません

# which -a convert
/usr/bin/which: no convert in (/home/xxxx/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/xxxx/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/xxxx/.local/bin:/home/xxxx/bin:/usr/local/go/bin)
```

**環境**
CentOS7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*-libs`というパッケージ名からも推測できるように、現状インストールされているのはImageMagickを外部から利用するための**共有ライブラリのみ**がインストールされている状態です。

rpmパッケージの詳細は`rpm -qi PACKAGE`(サマリ表示)や`rpm -ql PACKAGE`(パッケージに含まれるファイル一覧を表示)で確認してください。

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/ImageMagick6-libs-6.9.10.54-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

> Provides the shared libraries and plugins of ImageMagick6. This
>   package could be installed beside official RPM of ImageMagick for
>   applications requiring this libraries.

`convert`コマンドなどが含まれているのは(remiリポジトリから入手できるのは)
**ImageMagick6**パッケージです。

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/ImageMagick6-6.9.10.54-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

公式リポジトリでも提供されており、こちらでのパッケージ名は**ImageMagick**です。
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64.rpm