# FFmpegに同梱されている「avformat-59.dll」は誰が開発しているのですか？

Tags: dll

FFmpegに同梱されている「avformat-59.dll」は誰が開発しているのですか？
「FFmpegに同梱されている.dll」＝ 「FFmpeg が開発しているDLL」ということですか？　
[DLL とは](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library)には、

> Windows オペレーティング システムでは、オペレーティング システムの機能の多くが DLL によって提供されています。

と説明されているので、私はDLLは、どこかの技術系組織が開発して共通フォーマットを公開して配布＆一括管理しているのかと思っていました…(それをFFmpeg が使用しているのかと思っていました)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず「DLL = 共有ライブラリ」とは何かについて知った方が良さそうです。
DLL は Windows 向けで拡張子が `*.dll` ですが、Linux では `lib*.so` になります。

[共有ライブラリとは？ - Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA)

> 共有ライブラリとは、複数のプログラムが共通して利用する汎用性の高いプログラムの部品の集まりのことである。UNIX系のOSでは「.so.(バージョン番号)」という拡張子のファイルとして、また、Windowsの場合は「.DLL」という拡張子のファイルとして提供される。

なお、Linux における共有ライブラリ周りの話は、過去の re9 さんの質問に対していくつか回答しているはずです。

- [「rpm -qa | grep -i imagemagick」で結果が表示されるのに、convertコマンドが使えない理由は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/56715)
- [ChromeDriver インストールする際、libX11、GConf2、fontconfigライブラリもインストールする理由は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/61496)

---

`avformat-XX.dll` は Linux では `libavformat.so.XX` になりますが、Wikipedia で [FFmpeg](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) のページには以下の記載があります。

> libavcodec（動画/音声のコーデックライブラリ）、**libavformat**（動画/音声のコンテナライブラリ）、libswscale（色空間・サイズ変換ライブラリ）、libavfilter（動画のフィルタリングライブラリ）などを含む。

また、FFmpeg 公式のドキュメントページにも [Libavformat](https://ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html) に関するページがあるので、`avformat-59.dll` は **FFmpeg プロジェクトの成果物** と考えて良さそうです。

Comment: 「*.dll」や「lib*.so」は共有ライブラリとのことですが、それぞれ仕様はありますか？　例えば「*.dll」として仕様があり「HTML5仕様」のように「*.dll仕様」としてどこかで公開されていますか？　それとも「*.dll」は単にこの拡張子を共有ライブラリとしてみなすという意味でしかなく、それぞれの仕様は、同じ「*.dll」でもそれぞれのプロジェクトごとに異なるのですか？　また「*.dll」や「lib*.so」が何の言語で書かれたかファイル名から判別できますか(逆に言えば何の言語で書いても良い？)？

Comment: まじめに回答書くとコメント欄で収まらないし、そもそも解決チェックを付けてしまった質問のコメント欄で続けるには良い新規質問なので新規発言でどうぞ